# (TypeScript) Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: typescript

I'm building a TypeScript + React app and I want to save form values into an array of objects. However, I get `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)` from `newFormValues[i][e.target.name]` in the function `handleChange` which I understand is because `e.target.name` should be a numeric value, however, is there a different way I can read the value off each field without using `[e.target.name]`?

```
type FormValueType = {
  name: string;
  numOfClasses: number;
  price: number;
}[];

function App() {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<FormValueType>([{name:"", numOfClasses: 0, price: 0}])

  const addStudioFields = () => {
    setFormValues([...formValues, {name: "", numOfClasses:0, price:0}])
  }

  const handleChange = (i: number, e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let newFormValues = [{...formValues}];
    newFormValues[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setFormValues(newFormValues)
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Class Picker</h1>
        <h2>
          Find the best membership option
        </h2>
        <div className="studios-container">
        <form>
          {formValues.map((element, index) => (
            <div className="form-inline" key={index}>
              <label>name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" value={element.name || ""} onChange={e => handleChange(index,e)}/>
              <label>period</label>
              <input type="number" name="numberOfClasses" value={element.numOfClasses || 0} onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)} />
              <label>price</label>
              <input type="number" name="price" value={element.price || 0} onChange={e => handleChange(index,e)}/>
            </div>
          ))}
        </form>
        <button className="button add" type="button" onClick={() => addStudioFields()}>Add</button>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of letting TypeScript inferring the type of `newFormValues`, you should give it an explicit type.
Something like: `const newFormValues: Array<Record<keyof FormValueType, any>> = [{...formValues}];`
(Not too sure about the type of `formValues`.)